# Package nleqslv Error: Length of fn result <> length of x

Tags: r

I am solving a nonlinear equation using the package nleqslv, but I keep getting the error: Length of fn result <> length of x!

I can't spot the place where vector length can be a problem. Anyone knows what mistakes did I made in my code?

```
library(nleqslv)

d_plus <- function(x)  (log(55.75/x[1])+(0.026 + x[2]^2 / 2) * 0.25) / (x[2]*0.5) + 0 * x[3]

d_minus <- function(x) (log(55.75/x[1])+(0.026 - x[2]^2 / 2) * 0.25) / (x[2]*0.5) + 0 * x[3]

F_C0 <- function(x) 55.75 * pnorm(d_plus(x)) - x[1] * exp(-0.026 * 0.25) * pnorm(d_minus(x)) + 0 * x[3]

eqn <- function(x) F_C0(x) - x[3]

nleqslv( c(40, 1, 17.35), eqn)
```

I am trying to solve for x[2] and I have the input of x[1] and x[3]. It looks like I should get the numeric solution of x[2].

Comment: `pnorm` is vectorised in its first function argument `q`. Since `F_C0` accepts a `vector` `x` which you then pass on to `pnorm`, `pnorm` returns a vector (which you then operate on with scalars) and so does the whole function `F_C0`. Could that be the reason for the error? Otherwise it would help if you were to explicitly write down the non-linear equation with some explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible since you have not shown all your code: `library(nleqslv)` is missing. Please show all your code.

As the first comment on your question stated you are providing a vector to `eqn` but functions `d_plus`, `d_minus` and thus `F_C0` return a scalar.
That implies that the length of the function result is not the same as the length of the input.

From your explanation you want to solve for `x[2]`. So the function presented to `nleqslv` must take a scalar as input and return a scalar.

This can be achieved as follows:

```
library(nleqslv)

d_plus <- function(x)  (log(55.75/x[1])+(0.026 + x[2]^2 / 2) * 0.25) / (x[2]*0.5) + 0 * x[3]

d_minus <- function(x) (log(55.75/x[1])+(0.026 - x[2]^2 / 2) * 0.25) / (x[2]*0.5) + 0 * x[3]

F_C0 <- function(x) 55.75 * pnorm(d_plus(x)) - x[1] * exp(-0.026 * 0.25) * pnorm(d_minus(x)) + 0 * x[3]

eqn <- function(xpar) { x <- c(40,xpar,17.35);F_C0(x) - x[3] }
```

Insert the scalar argument of `eqn`, which is your `x[2]`, into a vector `x` where the first and third entries are what you provided as starting values in your code .
Then running this

```
xstart <- 1
nleqslv( xstart, eqn)
```

results in this

```
$x
[1] 0.6815036

$fvec
[1] 6.18563e-11

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1

$nfcnt
[1] 5

$njcnt
[1] 1

$iter
[1] 5
```

Read the documentation of `nleqslv` to see what these items mean.
As you can see `nleqslv` found a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It looks like I always have to match the number of real equations with the number of real unknowns.

Comment: Yes and the documentation for argument `fn` of `nleqslv`  says so.